# (Java 1.16.2)My custom model data didn't work with files I added

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I want to make custom model textures for the wooden sword. Below is the wooden_sword.json:

```
{
  "parent": "item/handheld",
  "textures": {
    "layer0": "item/wooden_sword"
  },
  
  "overrides":[
  {"predicate": {"custom_model_data":1}, "model":"item/iron_ingot"},
  {"predicate": {"custom_model_data":2}, "model":"item/gold"}
  ]
}
```

It showed the texture of "item/iron_ingot"(minecraft's original file) correctly, but it only showed error texture when using the "item/gold" that I added my own. I think it cannot detect the file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the model you are calling is valid (the 'gold' model) for help you can look at default models in the default minecraft resource pack.  I also suggest turning on the debug window at launch of minecraft, it really helps.  It can be turned on in the launcher in settings under general.  Below is a video about custom model data you should probably watch.

You might be also miscalling the model.
I hope this helps.